# Query a block explorer to return the balance of a specific type of token in an ethereum address?

Tags: tokens, addresses, explorers, explorer-api

Is there a block explorer where one can query an address and it outputs the balance of a specific type of token? Is there an example of how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done pretty easily [just using the Web3 APIs for standard tokens](https://github.com/shawntabrizi/ERC-20-Token-Balance).

Etherscan also supports showing all the tokens that an address has in the "Token Balance" section:

[image]

Comment: i need it via an api call with json returned. I can't click it.

Comment: The first link I posted has a way you can call via the Web3 API